# Prevent Contacts from forcing me to save to a logged in gmail account?

Tags: contacts, accounts

If I have a logged in gmail account (say, for example, in the play store), the phone absolutely forces me to save contacts, calendar appointments, etc. to the gmail account.

For example, if I add a contact, I'm supposed to be able to say *where* I want to save the account to (my email account, the device itself, etc). It will *not* allow me to save to the device (that's not even a selectable option).

What do?

Device is a Moto Z Play, Android version 8.0.0

Comment: even worse local saved contacts will move to google contacts (for example when saved to phone with MyPhoneExplorer)

Comment: Disable `Google Contacts Sync` app (root is required). Or try revoking Contacts permission and all AppOps of the same app. Works for me, I manually sync contacts, not to Google servers.